# Provisional headers are shown and pending requests

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome, vue-resource

I have a problem with vue-resource causing a **Provisional headers are shown** on Chrome, using jQuery on the other hand work without any problem

**The problem only happens with Chrome + vue-resource**

[image: Error]

#### Reproduction Link

Chrome 57.0.2987
Windows 7

I don't have adblock or origin installed, and it happen even on guest mode on Chrome

A simple call set with setInterval

```
new Vue({

  el: '#main',

  data: {
    summary: null
  },
        methods: {
            updateSummary: function() {
      /*
                $.post( "summary.php", function( data ) {
                    if(typeof response.body.summary != 'undefined'){
                        this.summary = response.body.summary;
                    }
                });
        */
                this.$http.post('summary.php').then(function(response) {
                    if(typeof response.body.summary != 'undefined'){
                        this.summary = response.body.summary;
                    }
                });
            }
      },
        mounted: function () {
            this.updateSummary();

            setInterval(function () {
                this.updateSummary();
            }.bind(this), 2000);
        }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7vo2s8z3/1/

#### Steps to reproduce

usually it happens when I leave the page open for a few hours

#### What is Expected?

A 200 code response with content served

#### What is actually happening?

I get a request with these headers

> Request URL:http://127.0.0.1:8080/monitor/summary.php
> Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
> Request Headers
>
> **Provisional headers are shown**
> Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
> Content-Type:application/json;charset=utf-8
> Origin:http://127.0.0.1:8080
> Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8080/monitor/
> User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
> X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest

And looking at **chrome://net-internals/#events** the cause of failure is

> 85487: URL_REQUEST
> http://127.0.0.1:8080/monitor/summary.php
> Start Time: 2017-04-18 09:38:43.826
>
> t=29028 [st=    0] +REQUEST_ALIVE  [dt=24184]
> --> priority = "MEDIUM"
> --> url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/monitor/summary.php"
> t=29029 [st=    1]   +DELEGATE_INFO  [dt=24183]
> --> delegate_blocked_by = "RedirectToFileResourceHandler"
> t=53211 [st=24183]      CANCELLED
> --> net_error = -2 (ERR_FAILED)
> t=53212 [st=24184] -REQUEST_ALIVE

Comment: Anything in your apache/nginx log?

Comment: nothing, the request isnt reaching the nginx

Comment: @Tarik I've same issue like you on chrome 72 with vue and axios. post request does not sent. but it work on get. how to solve it?

Comment: I didnt manage to solve it, the problem originated from having the ajax in a loop and people leaving the dashboard running overnight which break at some point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this happens when the actual request is not sent, usually when you are loading a cached resource.

Basically you sent a POST request to port 8080 which caused the "CAUTION: provisional headers are shown" message as seen in the inspector and then it seems the request was blocked all together.

Based on that, one possible solution is to setup nginx to proxy pass the request from the usual SSL port of 443 to the node SSL port of 8080 (node has to be on a higher port as it cannot be ran as root in prod). I guess Chrome doesn't like SSL requests to unconventional SSL ports, though I definitely agree their error message could be more specific.

Comment: the problem isnt relevent only in port 8080, and the request isnt reaching nginx at all as you said